# Get URL variable in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I m in a situation where i am redirecting user to another page with following jQuery code

```
window.location = "/#/customer/email?isEmail=true&eid=1&template=2";
```

i have some url re-writing , and so complete url becomes is

```
https://demo.qa.com/#/customer/email?isEmail=true&eid=1&template=2
```

but in PHP when i try to get full page url using this

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

it just gives me this

```
/
```

i just want to get variable IsEmail

```
$_GET['IsEmail']
```

value in PHP page,

I think the

```
#
```

in between the URL is creating the problem, is there any way to get it, please advise..

Comment: maybe try using substr  http://us3.php.net/substr

Comment: @cook that won't work if PHP doesn't have a value to use for substr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fragment is never sent to the server, so if you want access to the query parameters you need to bring them forward:

```
https://demo.qa.com/?isEmail=true&eid=1&template=2#/customer/email
                    ^                             ^
                    query                         fragment
```

Answer (score 1):

The anchor fragment portion of the URL (anything after `#`) isn't sent to the server at all.  It only lives client-side.  The server has no knowledge of it, and therefore PHP has no knowledge of it.

If you want to do anything with the anchor fragment, you must do it client-side.